# Answer promotes bad practice coding

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I'm a developer who has done a lot of work using Laravel and as such, I spend a couple of minutes a day on the Laravel/PHP board to answer some questions.

Lately I have noticed that a lot of people use Laravel while they have no idea how to code properly. It's understandable because Laravel is easy to use and the built in (security) checks are quite fool proof to some degree. The result of these people trying Laravel however, is that mostly around a third of the questions asked are either about really basic skills or about stuff OP clearly doesn't understand.

These questions often receive a few downvotes, but a lot of questions still receive answers by fellow SOers who just want to score some quick reputation. They give an answer that's technically correct and will solve OP's problem, but that answer 99% of the time either promotes bad practice coding or provides a copy-paste solution. OP will then copy-paste and continue asking questions in the comments because "it still not work", which is logical because the rest of the code is one big bowl of spaghetti.

2 examples as of late:

[OP seems to ask a question about why specific Laravel functionality was deprecated and then turns to an answer that implements exactly that functionality that Laravel chose to deprecate because it's really bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672038/explain-how-to-use-session-in-the-constructor-laravel-5-3)

[OP doesn't understand Model-View-Controller architecture (or OOP for that matter) and just copy-pasted the first thing that worked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662236/saving-object-in-a-class-variable-and-using-it-in-another-function-php-larave)

Both of the questions had answer that explained why OP shouldn't do what he does and he/she just ignores that and carries on. Is there something we should do about this and if yes, what is it? I've seen this happen on other boards, but all the questions get downvoted so fast nobody takes their answer seriously. On the Laravel boards a question rarely receives more than two downvotes and thus OP and other beginner programmers think that it was a valid question with a valid answer.

Now I understand that we shouldn't just shut down every "bad" question. Everybody started without any knowledge. It's just that we seem to promote bad coding more and more as of late, and I'd hate for us to teach a new generation of developers that bad coding is alright.

**TL;DR**

What should I / we do with bad questions that attract equally bad answers?

Comment: Downvote the bad answers and leave a comment explaining why they're bad.  What more can you do?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know. That solution seems to have no effect, so maybe someone other than me or my colleagues had a good tip or solution

Comment: Let me expand on my answer a bit.  Most people don't give a fuck about quality, security, or anything else.  There's nothing you can do to reach them-  they're going to pump out code in the quickest, hackiest method possible because its all they're capable of and they don't have the ambition to improve.  Many of them are subcontractors or sub-subcontractors who just ned to pump out code to get paid., and have no incentive to do well.  Nothing you do will stop those people.  All you can do is explain the right way to do things to try and explain it to the percentage who do care.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm always a "the glass is half full" type, but I guess some people are unwilling to change it doesn't suit their needs. Leaving open for suggestions though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions and answers should be voted on (up/down/close) based on their merits.

One of the important things to keep in mind that all posts are meant for **future** visitors. You can ask yourself: *If I stumble on this question and their answers, what should be the take-away*.

So if a question (and/or answers) advocates bad practice by today's standard, leave an answer that explains, provide facts, shares background information and demonstrates clearly why it is a bad practice. So what is the risk continuing doing that, what is the benefit of the preferred approach, how will it improve etc.

If an answer(or comment for that matter) only *yells* at the OP that they are doing it [wrong](https://xkcd.com/386/), at best it will become a mud-fight without any benefit and only angry users.

In the end it is up to the OP of the question which answer worked for them, marking it as accepted. That this might lead to an answer promoting not the best practice should be signaled by the community by down voting such answers.

Comment: Neither of the four answers on the two linked questions have attracted any downvotes so far though. It looks like the community either doesn't care, or doesn't consider the examples cases of bad practice...

Comment: @user000001 yes I noticed that but I have not touched PHP so I explictely stayed away from giving my opinion about those posts. Again, that is up for the PHP tag followers to deal with.